# Function with variable length argument list

Tags: php, function

If I have the following function:

```
function foo($a = 'a', $b = 'b', $c = 'c', $d = 'd')
{
    // Do something
}
```

Can I call this function and only pass the value for $d, therefore leaving all the other arguments with their defaults? With code something like this:

```
foo('bar');
```

Or do I have to call it with something like this:

```
foo(null, null, null, 'bar');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968965/php-default-arguments

Comment: @Quasdunk, do you mean call it like `foo('', '', '', 'bar')`?

Comment: You have to pass all previous arguments, since PHP does not support named arguments as Python does. But see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559305/php-passing-array-to-function/7559391#7559391) can help you

Comment: How would PHP know which argument you'd supplied? It's quite blatantly physically impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. Use arrays:

```
function foo($args) {
   extract($args);
   echo $bar + $baz;
}

foo(array("bar" => 123, "baz" => 456));
```

Write a bug report on php.net and ask them to add named arguments to the language!

Comment: Please don't write a bug report on php.net asking for named arguments as several have been written over the years, so any new bug would be a duplicate. There has been lots of discussion on the topic between the developers (even recently) with no decision to add this feature to PHP.  However, do feel free to draft an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc) on the subject and discuss it (again) on the [PHP internals mailing list](http://php.net/mailing-lists.php).

Comment: absolutely true, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use nulls like you said:

```
foo(null, null, null, 'bar');
```

If you don't mind creating more functions you could do something like this, I'd imagine the overall code would be neater.

```
function update_d($val){
    foo(null, null, null, $val);
}
```

Or you could use arrays like so:

```
$args = array($a = 'a', $b = 'b', $c = 'c', $d = 'd');
foo($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like

```
foo(null, null, null, 'bar');
```

An alternative is to leave the arguments out of the function signature, and use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to retrieve the values;

```
function foo() {
    $args = func_get_args();
```

But then still, if you would leave out the first three `null` values, there's no way to know that 'bar' is the `$d` parameter. Note by the way that this approach is undesirable most of the times, because it obfuscates your function signature and hurts performance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.
Long answer: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.

Default argument value will be used when the variable is not set at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) techniques.

In this case, your program assumes that if only one param is passed, it's the fourth.

Answer (score -1):

[func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) - Gets an array of the function's argument list.
[func_num_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) - Returns the number of arguments passed to the function

```
function foo()
{
     $numargs = func_num_args();
     echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
}


foo(a); foo(1,b,c); will work fine
```